remove outline around transparency
I have created a textured object that needs to fade to transparency at one end. I have managed this but can't seem to remove a black keyline that appears where the object is transparent. See image.
Does anybody have any ideas? I have both blend and shadow modes set to alpha hashed and I have tried removing the reflective and gloss maps from the image texture but nothing has made a difference.
Add. This is occurring in cycles renders
Blend file can be downloaded here: https://www.isle.co.uk/work/transparency-issue.blend


hello could you please share the object?

shared: https://www.isle.co.uk/work/transparency%20issue.blend

weird, I can't even open your file

Hi, must have got corrupted it's saying it's missing a data block. This should work I've just checked it on my machine. https://www.isle.co.uk/work/transparency-issue.blend

if you are using 4.2 it seems to work fine, at least on my computer I can't see this black line

The line won't show until it's rendered

I can't tell why it doesn't work for you, it seems to work for me: https://zupimages.net/up/24/39/odlt.png

Are you rendering in evee or cycles?

Eevee in 4.2, before this version you need to choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend in the Material panel > Settings

I need the output in cycles. This must be where the problem arises

The Principled BSDF already have an "alpha" input, so no need to mix it to an extra Transparent BSDF node, you could just plug your gradient in the Alpha input. You also don't seem to be doing anything with the Mapping node, and the Y channel of the Gradient texture coordinate is already a gradient so no need for a gradient node either. Just invert the Color Ramp and ajust a bit (I also use Ease interpolation to ensure no color bleeding past the color stops). Which gives you a much simpler node setup, and probably better performances if it were done at large scale:

Your issue seems to come from the displacement in the transparent area. An easy way to fix it would be to subtract your transparency mask to it:


Thanks Lauloque.
